# Tikz graph's circle makes strange number in drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, circles

Im making some network diagrams and whanted to build a star-topologie schematic. I do not know where the circle in the middle and its number is comming from:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{%
  graphs,
  graphs.standard,
  }
\begin{document}
      \tikz \graph [simple, nodes={circle,draw}] {
        subgraph K_n [n=6, clockwise];  % Get rid of the following edges: 
        1 -!- 2; 1 -!- 3; 1 -!- 5; 1 -!- 6  
        2 -!- 3; 2 -!- 4; 2 -!- 6;
        3 -!- 2; 3 -!- 4; 3 -!- 5;
        4 -!- 5; 4 -!- 6;
        5 -!- 6;
        6 -!- 1;
        }; 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: remove `1 -!- 6  `  from this line `1 -!- 2; 1 -!- 3; 1 -!- 5; 1 -!- 6`

Comment: yep, that did it. but i dont understand why. anyway, thanks @CroCo

Comment: You are saying `1 -!- 6 2` so you get a `6 2` node.

Comment: omg! im miss the semicolon! such a easy failure. thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was related to a simple syntax error